# extjs - How to submit a form when the response is not json?

Tags: json, forms, extjs, extjs4

I understand that when I submit a form, according to [the documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-submit) ExtJs by default parses the response as JSON.

In my case, the server returns HTML, that I want to display in a Panel. When I submit the from using `getForm().submit()`, ExtJs will throw an error about invalid JSON:

```
Ext.JSON.decode(): You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String
```

How can I tell ExtJs not to attempt to parse the response ? I could the access the text with the [response object](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.action.Action-property-response).

Comment: Don't you think that AJAX will be more suitable here?

Comment: I could change the server's response into `{html: '<my html bribe>'}`. But if it's possible to change the client side, I'd prefer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it was impossible for me to get to work the `form.submit()` of ExtJs. I needed an implementation using `Ext`. And since this is a frequent pattern in my application, it is important to have a short an simple solution.

This is what I finally found (I have a modal window containing the form):

```
var values = me.up('form').getValues(),
panel = Ext.create('My.view.MyPanel', {
    xtype: 'panel',
    loader: {
        url: Paths.ajax + 'sav_vpc/douane.php',
        method: 'get',
        params: values,
        autoLoad: true
    }
});
me.up('window').close()
```

This solution has another advantage over the `me.up('form').getForm().submit()` solution:

While `.getForm().submit()` is asynchronous, `.getValues()` is synchronous. Therefore, it is possible to close the window immediately.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you are looking for strictly an ExtJS framework solution. However, it seems you may be able to solve your issue possibly using xmlhttprequest directly since you are looking to push the `html` returned directly to `dom`?

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open('GET','/myPath/here',false);
xmlhttp.send();
var html = xmlhttp.responseText;
//assign value
```

Comment: Example available here: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first

Answer (score 0):

In `Ext.form.Basic` configuration you can define your own [reader](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-cfg-reader) and [errorReader](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-cfg-errorReader)

Comment: This doesn't really help, because there are only ajax, array and xml readers. There is nothing simpler, and I don't think I'm ready to write my own extension `Ext.data.reader.Html`. I think `getForm().submit()` isn't the right approach to the problem.