# ExtJS 5 - Calling Java servlet export using form submit return decoding error

Tags: javascript, extjs, ria

I am trying to call Java servlet export functionality using ExtJS form submit method to download CSV file. The request completed successfully with 200 response code,but still the program fails with the following error message.

**Error message:-**

```
Ext.JSON.decode(): You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String
```

**Code Snippet:-**

```
   var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel');
   form.submit({
     method  : 'POST',
     url     : GRID_EXPORT_URL,        
     params  : {
        gridId : this.getView().gridId
     },
     headers : {
        "USER": user,
        "SERVERSESSIONID": serverSessionId,
        "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
     },
     target: '_blank'        
   });
```

I referred the following stakoverflow question, but that didn't help much in my case.

[extjs - How to submit a form when the response is not json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20491378/extjs-how-to-submit-a-form-when-the-response-is-not-json)

Thanks!

Comment: I got it work based on this stackoveflow link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29012888/extjs-5-download-file-from-post-servlet-request/29414650#29414650.

Answer (score 1):

`form.submit` is not really the right way to approach this.

Make it a plain [Ext.Ajax.request](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Ajax-method-request) without a success handler (you can/should still handle server side failures). That'll most likely work.